# How widely accepted is the euro in Bosnia and Herzegovina?

Tags: money, bosnia

The official currency is the [convertible mark (BAM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosnia_and_Herzegovina_convertible_mark), but I saw some mentions that the euro is accepted in Bosnia as well.

How widely can you pay with euros? In restaurants, hotels, bars, public transport, taxis, and so on.

Comment: Fairly widely, but generally at a 2:1 rate, which is slightly less favorable than the official 1.95583:1 rate.

Comment: @phoog - less favorable, but much easier to calculate in your head...

Comment: @phoog given that the official rate is 1EUR=1.95583BAM, a 2:1 rate for cash payment in Euros is slightly *more* favourable to the visitor, not *less* so.

Comment: @MadHatter true. I think I was confused by The recollection of a transaction I made several years ago in which I was also concerned with the USD exchange rate.  I almost never use euros in Bosnia.

Comment: @phoog, thanks! If you can elaborate on "fairly widely" a little, that would make for a good answer to this question ;)

Comment: @Jonik sadly, as I mentioned before, I generally don't use EUR when I'm there.  I get the impression that it's more likely to be accepted for larger transactions.  I doubt you can pay bus or tram fares with euros, for example, or for smaller shop purchases.  Also, my experience is almost entirely limited to Sarajevo, so it's likely to be different elsewhere.

Comment: Why not just exchange a bit of cash and use your card where possible?

Comment: @JonathanReez but then we wouldn't have this nice and interesting question

Answer (score 1):

The useful World Travel Guide (WTG) currency information for Bosnia and Herzegovina says that, yes, **some** Euro notes are widely accepted. In my experience, that means denominations greater than 20€ (i.e., 50€ or 100€) are more difficult to use, unless being exchanged or getting smaller value bills (e.g., in a bank). Added emphasis mine.

> **Currency information**
>
> Bosnia and Herzegovina Konvertibilna Marka (BAM; symbol KM) = 100 feninga. Notes are in denominations of KM200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 and 1 and 50 feninga. Coins are available in denominations of KM2 and 1, and 50, 20 and 10 feninga. ***Some Euro notes (but not coins) are widely accepted.***
>
> **Credit cards**
>   Credit cards are generally accepted in top hotels and restaurants, and some gift shops. ATMs are becoming increasingly common in cities like Sarajevo, Mostar and Banja Luka, and even smaller towns. However, an emergency supply of cash is still advisable.
>
> **ATM**
>   ATMs are becoming increasingly common in cities like Sarajevo, Mostar and Banja Luka, and even smaller towns.
>
> **Travellers cheques**
>   Bosnia and Herzegovina is mostly a cash-only economy and traveller's cheques are exchanged only at select banks.
>
> **Banking hours**
>   Mon-Fri 0800-1900.
>
> **Currency restrictions**
>   The import and export of local currency are limited to KM200,000. There are no restrictions on the import and export of foreign currencies.
>
> **Currency exchange**
>   The Euro and US Dollar are the preferred foreign currencies. The Pound Sterling is rarely used. ***Some shops will accept Euro cash for payment on a 2KM = 1 Euro basis.***

Comment: With regard to ATMs I would caution everyone to shop around for withdrawal fees.  Some banks have very high fees, while others have none.  An ATM with no fees can sometimes be identified more quickly from the fact that there is a line of people waiting to use it.